# How do I create a JButton solely on one pane that prints "Hello

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, jtabbedpane

Every time I try to do this, it gives me an error that "Change Listener cannot be converted to Action Listener" and even if I implement ActionListener to the class... it still gives me another error

Is there a way to create a JButton only on the pane "Encryption" that when pressed prints "Hello"

**This is my code:**

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent; 
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;  

public class SwingDemo extends JFrame    { 
   public static void main(String args[]) { 


  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Encryption/Decryption Software");
  JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
  JPanel panel1, panel2;
  panel1 = new JPanel();
  panel2 = new JPanel();
  tabbedPane.setBackground(Color.blue); 
  tabbedPane.setForeground(Color.white);
  tabbedPane.addTab("Encryption", panel1);
  tabbedPane.addTab("Decryption ", panel2); 
  frame.add(tabbedPane);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setBounds(200,170, 500,250);
  frame.setVisible(true);

  tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
      if(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex() == 0){

        panel1.removeAll();

        panel1.setLayout(null);

        JLabel initial_text = new JLabel("Enter text to be encrypted:");
        JLabel final_text = new JLabel("Final text:");
        JLabel key = new JLabel("Key:");

        JTextField text_field = new JTextField(100);
        JTextField key_field = new JTextField(100);

        panel1.add(initial_text);
        panel1.add(final_text);
        panel1.add(key);
        panel1.add(text_field);
        panel1.add(key_field);

        initial_text.setBounds(10, 20, 300, 50);
        final_text.setBounds(10, 150, 600, 50);
        key.setBounds(10, 58, 300, 50);
        text_field.setBounds(178, 30, 230, 30);
        key_field.setBounds(38, 72, 36, 25);




      }
    }
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly is the issue with your `JButton`? I don't see one here and I also can't follow your explanation. You may also change your approach, because right now, the panel and its contents are defined inside the changelistener. Therefore, on launch, the initially selected tab won't have the contents loaded. So you should probably initialize all contents and only reset all fields on the tab-change for example.

Comment: *it gives me an error that "Change Listener cannot be converted to Action Listener"* - so don't add a ChangeListener to the button. You need to use the `addActionListener()` method to add an `ActionListener` to the button.

Comment: I second @maloomeister's comment.  Create the entire GUI before making it visible to the user, then in the ActionListener, update the contents of your GUI.

Comment: @maloomeister If I had a button I can only do it with ChangeListener and it does not allow me to click on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to detect a click you need to add an MouseListener no a ChangeListener

Like this

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent; 
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;  
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class SwingDemo extends JFrame    { 
   public static void main(String args[]) { 

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Encryption/Decryption Software");

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Encryption/Decryption Software");

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    JPanel panel1, panel2;
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel2 = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane.setBackground(Color.blue);
    tabbedPane.setForeground(Color.white);
    tabbedPane.addTab("Encryption", panel1);
    tabbedPane.addTab("Decryption ", panel2);
    frame.add(tabbedPane);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBounds(200, 170, 500, 250);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    tabbedPane.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It gives me this: error: cannot find symbol
      tabbedPane.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                                      ^

Comment: you need to replace tabbedPane for the object that you want or also did you import the library that uses mouseListener?

Comment: There was a library missing, thank you! But now there's one last problem... How can I make it print "Hello" when the button "Encrypt" is pressed... I put this code Public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              if(e.getActionCommand() == "Encrypt"){
                System.out.println("Hello");
              }
          } ...inside mouseClicked at the end and it says error: illegal start of expression
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

Comment: you don't need to add if(e.getActionCommand){} you can do it without it

Comment: error: illegal start of expression
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          ^
This still happens...

Comment: I edited again an added almost everything you previosly had so you can try with this because I really don't understand the exception that you are getting, because for me that works fine.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code exactly how it is and this is what showed up... error: cannot find symbol
    tabbedpane.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    ^

Comment: I edited again, I even put it on netBeans and there was no error so I copied very single thing it had, and if now it dosn't work, I don't know what else to do

Comment: (1-) Don't use a MouseListener. You use a ChangeListener to be notified when a tab is clicked. If you use a JButton you add an ActionListener to the button.